# Word Search Puzzle: How do I search an array of letters to find a word?

Tags: c++, arrays, search

I am trying to create a word-search puzzle game that asks the user to enter a word they think is in the array, and if that word is found, then give the user a point (for a total of 10 points, after which a congratulatory message is printed).

In this code I have a regular array but based on some research I think a 2D array might be better. What are your thoughts? Specifically I am interested in what kind of search algorithm I should consider

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
// your code goes here

  cout<<"=================================================================================="<<endl; 
cout<<"||                                                                              ||"<<endl;
cout<<"||                        Welcome to the ECE 114 Game Design!                   ||"<<endl;
cout<<"||                                                                              ||"<<endl;
cout<<"=================================================================================="<<endl;   
cout<<"This is a sample output"<<endl; 


//We want to ask the user to enter a word that they think the cross-word puzzle contains
//if the puzzle contains that word, we tell the user they are correct and update their points
//score by 1. Total of 10 points to gain, when the points score reaches 10 the user gets congratulatory message

string myArray[] = { "A B C D E F G H
                      S P A D E T R Y
                      T I G O A L E A
                      T R A I N E A W
                      O A P B E A T N  "};
//The first array above will just be a visual for the player to see

//This second array is the one that I will use to search for words

 char wordBank[5][8] = [[ 'A', 'B ','C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],  
                    ['S','P', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'T', 'R', 'Y'], 
                    ['T', 'I', 'G', 'O', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'E', 'A'], 
                    ['T', 'R','A', 'I', 'N', 'E', 'A', 'W'], 
                    ['O', 'A', 'P', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'T', 'N']];

cout<<myArray<<endl;





return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is where an array (or 2 dimensional) array of characters would be better than one array of strings containing only one string.

Comment: Perhaps take note of [how to ask for help with homework questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Is this code compiling?  I suspect there would be a warning or error after the letter `H` in the array declaration.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am going to update it in a second with a 2D array. And the code isn't compiling. I am just writing psuedo code right now; I don't quite have the algorithm right

Comment: Look at `std::string::find` to search a string (horizontally).

Comment: You should be able to programmatically convert an arbitrary letter grid delimited with newlines into a two dimensional array of characters. There's no need to repeat it like this.

Comment: Your program definitely does not compile with your changes because you can only have one unique name per variable.  Your latest edits, you have `myArray` declared twice as arrays.  Your second array should be declared as `char myPuzzle[5][8] = {...};`.  Please review array declarations in your favorite C++ reference.

Comment: BTW, the puzzle is often called a *word search*.  A *crossword* puzzle usually has empty boxes and clues that need to be deciphered.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add some additional variables to make searching easier.  For example, create strings of the text in vertical and horizontal directions.

```
static const std::string puzzle_text[] =
{
  "ABCDEFGH",
  "SPADETRY",
  "TIGOALEA",
  "TRAINEAW",
  "OAPBEATN"
};

int main(void)
{
  std::string vertical_texts[8];
  for (unsigned int column = 0; column < 8; ++column)
  {
    for (unsigned int row = 0; row < 5; ++row)
    {
      vertical_text[column] += puzzle_text[row].at(column);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

By creating the strings for the vertical letters, the `std::string::find` can be used.  The vertical strings only need to be created once per puzzle.

Tasks for the OP:  reverse search (see `std::string` methods), and diagonal string creation.

**Edit 1: Search algorithm**
Here is an algorithm that I use with searching these puzzles:
1. Extract first letter of key word.
2. Search text row for letter.
3. If letter is found, check neighboring letters for 2nd letter of key word.
3.1. If 2nd letter is found, continue in direction and search for remaining letters of keyword.

This has served me well, especially for difficult to find words.

Comment: Thanks. I want to work with a 2D array instead. I've edited my post to show what I mean. Thanks for the explanation as well

Comment: The algorithms are the same whether the puzzle is a 2d matrix of characters or a 1d array of strings.  Understand them, then adapt them.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to implement a timer? This is just for improving my program and having some real stakes -- pride in this game. I want the user to know how long it takes them to complete the game (get all 10 words correct)

Comment: Timers are platform and OS dependent features.  Search the internet for your OS and the word "timer".  If they support timers, you should be able to see some examples.  For example, in embedded systems, we use the timer on the SOC.  When it elapses, it generates and interrupt.  In the interrupt service routine, we process the timer.  Windows may still have the wait on object API.